# Routing traffic in Google Cloud Platform based on Geo Location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

```
- - - - - - - - - GCP - VPC - - - - - -                  External device
|                                      |               ------------------- 
|   VM instance A       VM instance B  |   others      |    machine C    |
|     10.48.x.x   <--->  10.184.x.x   <------------->  |   public ipv4   |
|   Normal machine      Normal machine |               |       VPN       |
|_________^____________________________|               |_______^_________|
          |____________________________________________________|
                                  Singapore
```

I want to communicate C and A or C and B where instances A and B in the same VPC:

- Based on the public IPv4, if machine C's location is in Singapore, it will communicate with instance A
- Otherwise, machine C will communicate with instance B

I need keywords to research or suggestion to solve this problem, thanks for giving help

I am new to GCP

Comment: *"I need keywords to research"* - does [Google Cloud Router](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/router/how-to/create-router-vpc-network) works?

Comment: I have accessed the router and found it empty. What should I do with the cloud router now?

Comment: External Application load balancers can route the traffic to the backends based on the nearest geo locations. This [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https) will guide you in creating an External Application load balancer and configuring the geo location based routing to the nearest backend.

Comment: I have successfully completed the task, despite having only two regions (US and EU) throughout the tutorial. Thank you very much because I now know the next steps to take.

Comment: @BànhHảoToàn Since you said that the above comment is helpful for you in resolving the issue, for better visibility of the community, I'm posting the same as an answer.

Comment: My project manager has advised against using a load balancer, and it appears I need an alternative solution. Would you happen to have any suggestions that do not involve the use of a load balancer?

Comment: @BànhHảoToàn as mentioned [here](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/58491?locale=ja&parent=catalog#:~:text=01%3A30%3A00-,Cloud%20DNS%20%2D%20Traffic%20Steering%20using%20Geolocation%20Policy,-1%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%2030) you can also used Cloud DNS for traffic steering based on the geo locations.

Answer (score 0):

External Application load balancers can route the traffic to the backends based on the nearest geo locations. This [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https) will guide you in creating an External Application load balancer and configuring the geo location based routing to the nearest backend.

In the above documentation they have explained various things like path based routing,  closest region based routing and method to test whether all these configurations are working fine.

- Create instance groups: since you are using compute engine instances to serve as the backend for your load balancer you need to create instance groups
- Specify the port on which your application is running, create required firewall rules and reserve an external IP address for your load balancer
- Create a load balancer, configure the required health check rules and point your domain to the external IP of the load balancer.

Traffic is automatically routed to the nearest geo location. For testing this functionality you can ssh into any VM present in different geo locations and curl the url as mentioned in the “**[Testing multi-region functionality](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https#testing_multi-region_functionality)**” section.